# How to allow a Excel Sheet to stay active after initializing a combobox?

Tags: excel, combobox, excel-2007, vba

I wanted to know after I initialize a combobox, is there a possibility that I can still stay active with the background Excel sheet using the cursor like scroll the sheet up/down, type words on the sheet, etc?

(While at the same time the combobox still stays on top of the Excel sheet doing whatever event you might want to do with your VBA?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the VBA IDE and select your form.  In the properties list (on the left hand side of the screen), find the `ShowModal` property.  Set this to `False`.

This will prevent the dialog from taking over the window.

Comment: Thanks :) But just a side line a bit, how do i implement a minimize feature at the top right panel of a combobox just like a browser?

Comment: @Vivian I'll help you with it, but you should start a new question for a new topic

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972598/how-to-implement-a-minimize-feature-on-a-combobox-in-excel-vba

Comment: @Vivian Ok.  I've got a question for you over there