# How to Implement a minimize feature on a combobox in Excel-Vba?

Tags: excel, combobox, excel-2007, vba

Someone please help rather a newbie in Excel-Vba. How do i implement a minimize feature at the top right panel of a combobox something just like a browser?

Comment: What do you want to happen when you press the minimize button?  Where do you want the window to go?

Comment: @jonsca hidden at the taskbar? Not possible?

Comment: Somewhat possible, but see my comment after my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is modified from [this posting](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=25366&p=128696#post128696)

Drag a toggle button onto your form, and place this code anywhere in your module.  Click the toggle to "minimize" and again to reverse it.  Play around with the numbers to get the height and the position the way you want it.

```
Dim dWidth As Double
Dim wasTop, wasLeft As Integer
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
    If ToggleButton1.Value = True Then
        Me.Height = Me.Height * 0.25
        wasTop = Me.Top
        wasLeft = Me.Left
        Me.Top = 400
        Me.Left = 100
    Else
        Me.Height = dWidth
        Me.Top = wasTop
        Me.Left = wasLeft
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    dWidth = Me.Height
End Sub
```

Comment: @Vivian I guess there are a handful of examples that will minimize to the taskbar, but they involve some trickery see [this](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=66828) for example.  It doesn't sound like it's very reliable.

Comment: thanks for your concern. Appreciate it :) Can you take a look at another problem of mine here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991742/any-drag-and-drop-api-feature-in-excel-vba